# How to Synchronize Scroll of two RichTextBox without SystemOverflowException in WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, intptr

I made a code that synchronize a scroll of two RichTextBox.
Hope this works without a matter of line numbers.

but when the line of RichTextBox gets large (around 2000+), **System.OverflowException** occurs at SendMessage method.

Covering SendMessage with try/catch does not make it work.

Is there any way to handle IntPtr with a number which is greater than Int.MaxValue?

This is my code.
[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int a = 0; a < 4000; a++)
        {
            RTB1.Text += a + "\n";
            RTB2.Text += a + "\n";
        }
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public extern static int GetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public extern static int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private void RTB1_VScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int nPos = GetScrollPos(RTB1.Handle, (int)ScrollBarType.SbVert);
        nPos <<= 16;
        uint wParam = (uint)ScrollBarCommands.SB_THUMBPOSITION | (uint)nPos;
        SendMessage(RTB2.Handle, (int)Message.WM_VSCROLL, new IntPtr(wParam), new IntPtr(0)); //Error occurs here.
    }

    public enum ScrollBarType : uint
    {
        SbHorz = 0,
        SbVert = 1,
        SbCtl = 2,
        SbBoth = 3
    }

    public enum Message : uint
    {
        WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115
    }

    public enum ScrollBarCommands : uint
    {
        SB_THUMBPOSITION = 4
    }


}
```

Comment: The [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787577(v=vs.85).aspx) for WM_VSCROLL specifically talks about the "16-bit barrier" and what you do about it.  Use SetScrollInfo() instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your application is running as 32 bit and you're getting an Overflow because `UInt` can have a value which can't be fit in 32 bit signed `int`.

For instance, running your application as 64 bit should just work fine.

That said, you don't need that. You can simply avoid using `uint` and just use `int` which will work just fine.

```
int wParam = (int)ScrollBarCommands.SB_THUMBPOSITION | (int)nPos;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you said, either working on 64 bit platform, or change uint to int made it wok all fine.